# How to transform columns to rows in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table having below data , total 8 rows here sample for 3 rows -

[image]

now I transformed the query using case statement to this using below query -

```
select  
case when entity ='PRODUCT' then prd_table_main end P_main_prd ,
case when entity ='PRODUCT' then prd_table_sec end P_sec_prd,
case when entity ='CUSTOMER' then cus_table_main end P_main_cus ,
case when entity ='CUSTOMER' then cus_table_sec end p_sec_cus,
case when entity  ='PROFIT' then prof_table_main end p_main_prof ,
case when entity  ='PROFIT' then prof_table_sec end p_sec_prof
from (
select * from above table);
```

[image]

Now I want to have the o/p as in one row removing all the nulls. Basically I want to create a cursor and pass the value of tables to be used in the procedure as p_main_prd or p_sec_prd or the remaining ones as the requirement.

Comment: You are transposing rows to columns (not columns to rows) as you want to reduce the number of rows and increase the number of columns.

Comment: I'm lost.  You have column names named `table1` and `table2`.  Your query references *values* in columns, not column names.  What does the data really look like?  How many tables do you really have?

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, you just need to aggeregate:

```sql
select MAX( case when entity = 'product'  then table1 end ) AS P_main_prd,
       MAX( case when entity = 'product'  then table2 end ) AS P_sec_prd,
       MAX( case when entity = 'customer' then table1 end ) AS P_main_cus,
       MAX( case when entity = 'customer' then table2 end ) AS p_sec_cus,
       MAX( case when entity = 'profit'   then table1 end ) AS p_main_prof,
       MAX( case when entity = 'profit'   then table2 end ) AS p_sec_prof
from   table_name;
```

or use `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT prd_p_main AS p_main_prd,
       prd_p_sec AS p_sec_prd,
       cus_p_main AS p_main_cus,
       cus_p_sec AS p_sec_cus,
       prof_p_main AS p_main_prof,
       prof_p_sec AS p_sec_prof
FROM   table_name
PIVOT (
  MAX( table1 ) AS p_main,
  MAX( table2 ) AS p_sec
  FOR entity IN (
    'product' AS prd,
    'customer' AS cus,
    'profit' AS prof
  )
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( entity, table1, table2 ) AS
SELECT 'product', 'prd_table_main', 'prd_table_sec' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'customer', 'cus_table_main', 'cus_table_sec' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'profit', 'prof_table_main', 'prof_table_sec' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | P_MAIN_PRD | P_SEC_PRD | P_MAIN_CUS | P_SEC_CUS | P_MAIN_PROF | P_SEC_PROF |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | prd_table_main | prd_table_sec | cus_table_main | cus_table_sec | prof_table_main | prof_table_sec |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=41e42b616f0650ea3909742f1b3cb169)*

Comment: Thanks I need this exactly ~ :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try UNPIVOT. I'm not an expert on this, so I can only help you by giving you directions. Check this out, probably this will help you out, or at least show you another way:
[Oracle Unpivot](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-unpivot/#:%7E:text=The%20Oracle%20UNPIVOT%20clause%20allows,data%20during%20the%20transposing%20process.&text=In%20this%20syntax%3A,represents%20the%20unpivoted%20measure%20values.)

Comment: I want to have output in single row removing nulls